# How to join a polygon .kml file and text file based on the polygon name and create new layer

Tags: python, join, text, kml, polygon

I want to join a kml file that has all the counties with a txt file with county related data in Python.

Does anyone knows which library I can use? I couldn't do it with Fusion table.

Thanks
Mehrnoosh

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyKML](http://pythonhosted.org/pykml/) to read and manipulate KML files in python. You could use this to load your KML, then iterate over your objects and add the information from the text file to each element as appropriate. I would load the text file into a hash assuming that the country name is the key for both the text description and the KML element?